# How to find out Formular Names to use Post Request

Tags: python, html, post, authentication, python-requests

Im trying to login to a website using python requests. My code is as follows:

```
url = "https://program.uffiliates.com/en/Auth/Login"
    payload = {
    'uerName': '',
    'pasword': ''}

    try:
        with requests.Session() as s:
            r = s.post(url, data=payload)
            print(r.text)
    except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
        print(e)
    return
```

This doesnt work, it prints out the html-code of the login page and not what i should see when im logged in. I assume im using the wrong names of the formular. In the html code i find the following:

```
<form action="/en/Auth/LogInAction" method="post">
<input id="hiddenUrl" name="hiddenUrl" type="hidden" value="" />
<input id="SST_ID" name="SST_ID" type="hidden" value="2" />
<input id="serial" name="serial" type="hidden" value="" />
<input id="referer" name="referer" type="hidden" value="" />
```

This confuses me. Can someone tell me what names i have to use for the "payload" to put in my username and password.

And after logging in how can i navigate through the backend? Should i just use requests.get with the specific url since im already logged in, or should i somehow use requests to click on buttons/links to navigate?

Thanks alot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you need to `POST` your username and password via requests and be logged in.

first of all, the `url` you are posting the data to should be the form's action. not the login url.

secondly, there are a few hidden inputs in the URL, which I suspect the server will look at to confirm that the request is coming from an HTML that it recognises. You will need the inputs in your requests too.

try

```
url = "https://program.uffiliates.com/en/Auth/LogInAction"
    payload = {
    'uerName': '',
    'pasword': '',
    'hiddenUrl':'',
     'SST_ID' : '',
    'serial':'',
    'referer':''}

    try:
        with requests.Session() as s:
            r = s.post(url, data=payload)
            print(r.text)
    except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
        print(e)
    return
```

Comment: But how can I find out the values for the missing inputs? I tried the above with leaving the missing inputs just empty, but why i dont even get an error page or something similar? It just returns the page html. Thanks

Comment: It works now, i made a mistake with forgetting and "s" in username and password. Thanks again